# Select From List between two String item

Tags: c#, linq

i have this list , my date saved string format.for example , how i can select Dates between "93/01/01" and "93/01/10" with LINQ?

```
code            date
 1            "93/01/01"
 2            "93/01/02"
 3            "93/01/03"
 4            "93/01/04"
 5            "93/01/05"
 6            "93/01/06"
 7            "93/01/07"
 8            "93/01/08"
 9            "93/01/09"
 10           "93/01/10"
 11           "93/01/11"
 12           "93/01/12"
```

Comment: What type is your "list"?

Comment: if thats yy/mm/dd you can just compare the strings. your problem is of course is dates after 2000/01/01. However you approach the problem you have to decide if 93 is 93AD or 3093AD

Comment: Date values should (almost) always be stored as DateTime types especially if you are going to compare them.  As string they are no longer dates but mere text which compares differently.  If they are "yy/dd/mm"  format, it means "93/30/03" will compare as greater than "93/01/12"

Answer (score 1):

For a query that will return those results, 

`var asdf = liststuff.Where(
                    x =>
                        x.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/01") &&
                        x.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/10"));`

For a list that is executed and contains those results,

`var asdf = liststuff.Where(
                    x =>
                        x.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/01") &&
                        x.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/10")).ToList();`

The cautionary comments are all correct, but this will get you what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct Data
    {
        public Data(string keyValue, string strValue)
        {
            key = keyValue;
            date =  Convert.ToDateTime(strValue);
        }

        public string key { get; private set; }
        public DateTime date { get; private set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new List<Data>();
            test.Add(new Data("1", "93/01/01"));
            test.Add(new Data("2", "93/01/02"));
            test.Add(new Data("3", "93/01/03"));
            test.Add(new Data("4", "93/01/04"));
            test.Add(new Data("5", "93/01/05"));
            test.Add(new Data("6", "93/01/06"));
            test.Add(new Data("7", "93/01/07"));

            var asdf = test.Where(x => x.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/01") && x.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/10"));

        var asdff= from t in test
                   where t.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/01") && t.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("1993/01/10")
                   select t;

        }
    }
```

Just for add something as before, cause try on string <= with date will not work.